# How to know whether daylight saving is present for a country or not?

Tags: java, timezone, dst

I have a list of timezone values like we see in the Windows OS timezone dropdown.

If we select any timezone in the dropdown we get to know whether daylight saving is present or not.

How could I achieve this similar functionality? Currently, I have a similar list of values like we see in the Windows dropdown.

I understood that `TimeZone` object will solve this problem as it has a `boolean` property to state whether daylight saving present or not. But I am pretty much confused on how to create the `TimeZone` object with the available list of values.

I have the dropdown values like below:

- (UTC-12:00) International Date Line West
- (UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11
- (UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands
- (UTC-10:00) Hawaii
- (UTC-09:30) Marquesas Islands

With those sample values above, how could I create the `TimeZone` object?

Comment: You could look at [`TimeZone#getDSTSavings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDSTSavings--) and/or [`TimeZone#useDaylightTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#useDaylightTime--) and/or [`TimeZone#observesDaylightTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#observesDaylightTime--) and/or [`TimeZone#inDaylightTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#inDaylightTime-java.util.Date-)

Comment: You can create a `TimeZone` through [`TimeZone. getTimeZone(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.lang.String-) and/or [`TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.time.ZoneId-)

Comment: Thnaks for responding, yes i have seen with zoneID we could create object. but what if we have values like OS dropDwon things? how could we create the timeZone ?

Comment: You need to ascertain if the information you have can be mapped to the requirements of the `TimeZone` input, if not, you need to figure out how to map what information you have to the requirements of the API

Comment: Would it be acceptable to create your list of values from `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`? I doubt it would give you exactly the same list, even after some filtering, but it will give you only zone IDs that are recognized in Java, which will be a pleasant thing when you want to obtain UTC offset and whether summer time is in effect.

Comment: The values you are showing in that list are *display names*, not identifiers.  They are localized per language by Windows.  You should not be working with them in your application at all.

Answer (score 2):

It's a hard task. At [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), in the **"Time Zone Databases"** section, you'll see that Windows timezone names are very different from those in Iana/Olson database (which is the one used by Java).

In Java you can use `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`, or `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` if you have Java 8, to see all the available names - and see how they don't match Windows timezones list.

I think the best you can do is map each Windows name to a valid Iana's name, knowing that there's no perfect match for all cases: Iana database is more complete and accurate, specially for Daylight Saving data, including historical data - and also updated more often than Windows.

And the names are also very different, and Iana is more comprehensive and has more names - one Windows timezone name can refer to more than one from Iana. I'm not sure if there's an easy way to map all names from one to another.

But once you have those names, it's easy to check:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
// check if it has DST now or in the future (doesn't check the past)
boolean hasDST = zone.observesDaylightTime();

// check if a specific date is in DST
Date someDate = // some java.util.Date
boolean dateInDST = zone.inDaylightTime(someDate);
```

In Java 8:

```
ZoneRules rules = ZoneId.of("America/New_York").getRules();

// if it has DST, isFixed is false
boolean isFixed = rules.isFixedOffset();

// if lists are empty, offset never varies, so there's no DST
List<ZoneOffsetTransitionRule> transitionRules = rules.getTransitionRules();
List<ZoneOffsetTransition> transitions = rules.getTransitions();

// check a specific date (using java.time.Instant)
rules.isDaylightSavings(Instant.now());
// check a specific date (using java.util.Date)
Date date = new Date();
rules.isDaylightSavings(date.toInstant());
```

Note that an offset change doesn't necessarily mean DST. It can be just a simple change: the government decided to change the country's offset "permanently" - which means "until some other politician decides to change it again".

Daylight Saving is just a specific case of offset change, and there's no way to know if such change is DST related - like when a country decides to change to some offset and don't use DST; the zone will still be non-fixed (`isFixedOffset` returns `true`), because the offset changed.

In this case, you can use the transitions lists to know **when** those changes happen:

```
rules.getTransitions().forEach(t -> {
    // UTC instant that the change happens
    Instant instant = t.getInstant();

    // local date and time before the change
    LocalDateTime before = t.getDateTimeBefore();

    // local date and time after the change
    LocalDateTime after = t.getDateTimeAfter();
});
```

With this, you can know the exact dates that have offset changes.
Some timezones don't have transitions, but instead they have transition rules (such as "DST starts at the first Sunday of november"). In this case, you use the transition rules list:

```
rules.getTransitionRules().forEach(r -> {
    // check the rule for a specific year
    ZoneOffsetTransition t = r.createTransition(2018);

    // UTC instant that the change happens
    Instant instant = t.getInstant();

    // local date and time before the change
    LocalDateTime before = t.getDateTimeBefore();

    // local date and time after the change
    LocalDateTime after = t.getDateTimeAfter();
});
```

Comment: Use [CLDR](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) for mapping between Windows and IANA time zones.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using TimeZone as suggested in the comments to your question.

```
String zone = "(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West";

String zoneID = "GMT";
zoneID = zoneID + zone.substring(zone.indexOf("-"), zone.indexOf(")"));
System.out.println(zoneID);
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneID);
boolean answer = timeZone.observesDaylightTime();
System.out.print(answer);
```

Instead of using a string like I have, you can try using an Array List to iterate over all the values. Timezone accepts Zone ID in format as shown in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html

**UPDATE**

UTC doesn't use DST(source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), hence you would have to convert UTC to the target time zone or use a city name like zoneID = "America/New_York".
Updated code:

```
ZoneId zd = ZoneId.of(zoneID);
System.out.println(zd.getId());
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(
        LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2018, 4, 12), LocalTime.of(11, 30)), zd);
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
ZoneRules zr = zd.getRules();
System.out.println(zr.isDaylightSavings(instant));
```

Above code uses java 8 time classes. Also I have used `LocalDate` in April because in most countries where DST is observed, it gets applied somewhere in March.

Comment: String zone = "(UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands"; answer is giving like false, which is incorrect. daylightime is present for it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change UTC to GMT which the function recognizes. I see that Day light savings starts only in March, also inDaylightTime will tell you if it presently observes Day Light savings time. Updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks for response,but still String zone = "(UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands"; answer is giving like false, which is incorrect.

Comment: The `TimeZone` class is long outmoded. Please don’t teach the young ones to use it. Instead I recommend [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `ZoneId` class.

Comment: @OleV.V. I was actually updating my answer with `java.time` :); thanks!